# PrimeFaces dataExporter for Excel export. IE 9 prompt freezes blinking images located on a frame

Tags: excel, primefaces

I have a web page that consists of three "iframes". In one of them I have blanking images that represent activated alarms of equipment.
In another frame, I use the PrimeFaces "dataExporter" element to generate an Excel sheet with some data of a table.
When I push the button for Excel sheet generation, the Internet Explorer 9 shows the typical message ("Do you want to Open, Save or Cancel?").
No matter which option I choose, but the blanking images freeze. If I press F5 for refreshing, the images work well again (but this is unacceptable, it's a web for monitoring equipment).
I don´t understand what happens. I have proved with FireFox navigator and I have no problem. But it's necessary for me to works on IE 9 because it's a requisite of our customer.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
IFrame: upload_visir_files.xhtml
<f:view>
    <h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
    <title><h:outputLabel value="#{productmsg.upload_visir_file}" /></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body onload="window.top.hideWaitPanel()">
    <div id="div_body">
           ...
        <h:commandLink rendered="#{BackingUploadVisirFile.showExcelButton}" styleClass="excelButton" value="#{coremsg.exportExcel}"> 
            <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="visirFilesId" fileName="VisirFiles" pageOnly="true" /> 
        </h:commandLink> 

IFrame: status.xhtml

   <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ackPanelGrid">
    <h:graphicImage library="core/img" name="#{alarm.icon}" alt="#{corealarm.alarm}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>

The "#{alarm.icon}" contains the blinking image.
```

Comment: can you use another IE version? like 10? and are you using a meta-tag on the page? what have you tried? show us some code of how you bind the images.

Comment: Provide some code if possible.

Comment: I have just edited my question and provided some source code. On the other hand, I have proved with IE 10 and IE 8 and the problem appears as well.